# Im 14 and I ran 20 miles is that healthy

Tags: marathon

Is it really healthy to run that much for my age? I so how much should I run. Should I do it in moderation, or do it all in one day. I'm not sure if this is safe for my body. Please give me some feedback. I'm currently a long distance runner, so naturally I can handle that amount of stress on my body.

Comment: There is no table which tells you "if you're X years old, you can only run Y miles". We know nothing about your body, so the question can't be answered by us. You need to get a checkup at your doctor's.

Comment: Googling [safe mileage young runners](https://www.google.com/search?q=safe+mileage+young+runners&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) leads me to conclude that you'll be fine.

Comment: First of all you should learn to put question marks at the end of questions...

Answer (score 1):

Your body should be the one giving you feedback.
How is your body responding is the question you need to ask yourself and not just afterwards rather while you are running 
If you end up feeling overly stressed or ill than you probably want to tone it down.